# Cast exception when mocking kotlin lambda callbacks in Mockk

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I am having some trouble mocking callback functions with Mockk.

I am trying to mock a task success listener that is called like this:

```
collection
    .add(Item())
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        update(collection.document(it.id))
    }
```

Where the java signature for the callback would look like this:

```
public interface OnSuccessListener<T> {
    void onSuccess(T var1);
}
```

and the signature for addOnSuccessListener looks like this

```
public abstract Task<DocumentReference> addOnSuccessListener(@NonNull OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference> var1);
```

My mock looks like this:

```
every { documentReferenceTask.addOnSuccessListener(any()) } answers {
    firstArg<(DocumentReference) -> Unit>().onSuccess(documentReference)
    value
}
```

I have also tried:

```
every { documentReferenceTask.addOnSuccessListener(any()) } answers {
    firstArg<OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>>().invoke(documentReference)
    value
}
```

Either way, I am receiving a cast exception like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.package.MyClass$addProduct$1 cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1
```

Comment: Hi, what is signature for `addOnSuccessListener`?

Comment: I've updated the original post

Comment: I not totally understood. The issue is resolved, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, I was misreading the error.

```
every { documentReferenceTask.addOnSuccessListener(any()) } answers {
    firstArg<OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>>().invoke(documentReference)
    value
}
```

This method works, the cast exception was from the second line. The correction looks like

```
every { documentReferenceTask.addOnSuccessListener(any()) } answers {
    firstArg<OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>>().invoke(documentReference)
    **documentReferenceTask**
}
```